# Using MS Access w Azure sql server - why form opens slow

Tags: azure, performance, ms-access, database-performance

Using MS Access to connect to Azure Sql Server - want to see what queries are run when form is opened.  form has data source for it, subform and numerous combo boxes.  Want to see why it is taking so long before the form and subform displays.

So far I have tried removing parts of the form, like the subform, changing combo boxes to use local Access tables (in some cases).  Cannot figure out the root cause.

Have read about execution plans and can use the built in Query Store (enabled by default on Azure SQL Servers).  Can see regressed queries and individual queries.  But they look nothing like what my form should be doing.

Bob

Comment: The root course is, that Azure SQL is very (or rather: extremely) slow when run in a small  (cheap) instance. If you need speed, spend the bucks. By an hour or so and check it out.

Comment: We have an Azure subscription.  Can you elaborate on exactly what you are proposing?

Comment: Check what resources (vCore or DTU) you have available and the (extensive) options for  more [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/).

Answer (score 0):

When using MS Access and SQL Server you could obey some rules:

- open a form with only ONE record (e.g. with OpenForm "xx", Where:="ID = 100"
- Use first a form for filtering the data and then open an Edit-Form with only the selected record
- don't use complex queries as datasource for a form
- don't use a whole table as datasource for a form (when the table contains more than a dozen records)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Albert Kallal in another post provided the solution.  Set up a local SQL server express so you can use the SQL Server Profiler to see what is processed by sql server express.  The Profiler is not available in Azure which is what I am using.

Bob